# Import Material deisgn Layout Grid in Angular 4

Tags: css, angular, grid, material-design

I want to add [this](https://material.io/develop/web/components/layout-grid/) grid in my angular 4 project. I have installed these grid using

```
npm install @material/layout-grid
```

this command but now I am not able to import in my angular 4 project. My code is something like this

```
<div class="mdc-layout-grid">
  <div class="mdc-layout-grid__inner">
    <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell">One</div>
    <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell">Two</div>
    <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But my div are not aligning properly. Please see below image.

[image]

I am getting a result like this. What should I do to aligning div horizontally using this Layout Grid? Please help.

Comment: Don't you import the style?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to import css of this component I am getting warning while importing css

Comment: Scss imports look like this `@import "/path/to/my/file";` You should put this in your component's style's sheet.

Comment: If you are struggling with this, I recommend you to use the official material grid component from the @angular/material package https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview see guides in order to get started.

Comment: I want responsive grid don't want to write extra code for responsiveness that's why I am using layout grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you don't have imported css and js files to your angular project. Look on  `.angular-cli.json` file, there should be something like that:

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/path-to-your-module-css", // add this line 
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

Or you can also import that directly to your component css:

```
@import "../node_modules/path-to-your-module-css";
```

Comment: Is this a proper way to do this if I write css path mannualy in angular.cli.json file?

Comment: Yes, it is a proper way.

Comment: Thanks you @mathevs